# How to export in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: export, wolfram-cloud

So I'm using the Wolfram Cloud Development Platform to code in Mathematica and I'm trying to download an animation I made. I write `Export["conic.avi", conic]` and it outputs a result, but it doesn't appear anywhere in my cloud directory (neither in Home nor in Unnamed).

When using `ExpandFileName["conic.avi"]` I get `/wolframcloud/userfiles/559/559cdf6e-bef7-4e97-a8cb-a9c45b4cf81c/conic.avi` and using `SystemOpen` on that or on `conic.avi` sends me to a "Page not found" error.

Anyone knows a way to see where my animation is exported to? Or even to choose where to send it in the cloud?

Thanks

Comment: In order to organize and keep track of things, I usually export to a specific CloudObject.  So in your case, something akin to: `Export[CloudObject[""Exports/conic.avi"], conic]`.  Now the avi should be in your Exports folder.

Comment: @chuy Thank you! that worked :D

Comment: CloudExport[] should work as well.

Answer (score 6):

Revise the comment to an answer. The following is an working example:

```
anim = ListAnimate[Table[Region[RegularPolygon[r]], {r, 3, 30, 1}]]; 
Export[CloudObject["Exports/anim.avi"], anim, "AVI"]
```

Notice 3rd argument is necessary. Then the AVI file can be found in the Exports folder under Home directory of Wolfram cloud. (You can of course directly click the URL to download it. )

One can even simply write

```
Export[CloudObject@"anim.avi", anim, "AVI"]
```

Then the AVI file will appear in Home directory.

Alternatively, one can use `CloudExport`:

```
CloudExport[anim, "AVI", "anim.avi"]
```